# waits until the user finishes responding to the popup dialog in Swift

Tags: swift2

I want the user to type up the text in the pop up dialog, but I want the program to wait until the user finished writing the text in the pop up dialog

Comment: `UIAlertController`, `addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler`, `UIAlertControllerStyleAlert`, ...

Comment: Can you elaborate please?      
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Adding location", message: "write a quick description", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Click", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
        alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({(textField: UITextField!) in
            textField.placeholder = "Enter text:"
            textField.secureTextEntry = true
        })
        
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: Implement handler in addAction. It's called when button is tapped. That's the place where your program should continue. Either display the alert again (wrong input) or continue. You can't present alert and wait in the same place, otherwise you're going to block main thread - freeze. You have to handle input in action handler.

Answer (score 0):

Use `UIAlertController`:

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "title", message: nil, preferredStyle: .Alert)
alertController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField) -> Void in }
alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil))
logInAlertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "go", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in }
```

Answer (score 0):

### Swift 4

It sounds like you are doing your completion handling when presenting the controller instead of when the user selects an alert action.

You'll want to try something like this:

```
import UIKit

class MyViewController: UIViewController
{
    var someStringVariable:String = ""

    func presentAnAlert()
    {
        let alert = UIAlertController(
                title: "Title",
                message: "Message",
                preferredStyle: .actionSheet //choose which style you prefer
        )

        alert.addTextField()
        { (textField) in
            //this is for configuring the text field the user will see
            textField.borderStyle = UITextField.BorderStyle.bezel
        }

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default)
        { action in
            //use this space to transfer any data
            let textField = alert.textFields![0]
            self.someStringVariable = textField.text ?? ""
        })

        self.present(alert, animated: true)
        {
            //this will run once the action of **presenting** the view
            //is complete, rather than when the presented view has been
            //dismissed
        }
    }

    override viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.presentAnAlert()
        print(self.someStringVariable)
        //prints whatever the user input before pressing the OK button
    }
}
```

I hope that helped!